# Migrating Feedburner feeds to another account

Tags: rss, google-account, migration

I would like to migrate all my Feedburner feeds to another Google Account. I've been looking to add another user as Administrator like it is allowed in Google Analytics but haven't really found the option.

Does anyone know how I can give my new Google Account access to the feeds in Feedburner in my old Google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your old account, go to the Feedburner dashboard, click on a feed. Unde the feed's title, you will find a "Transfer feed..." link.